# AM-GM inequality for functions

Tags: functions, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

As all you masters in math know, the famous AM-GM inequality in positive numbers is as follows:

> $${1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\ge \left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}x_k\right)^{1\over n}$$

which can be rewritten in the following  alternative form:

> $$\large{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\ge e^{{1\over n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln x_k}$$

An interpretation says that **the (ordinary or arithmetic) average of a bunch of data, $x_k$, is not smaller than the exponential of the average of $\ln x_k$s**.

Now, if we interpret $x_k$s as infinitesimal parts of some function ,say $f(x)$, and correspondingly consider $\ln x_k$ as infinitesimal parts of $\ln f(x)$, intuition says:

> $$\large{1\over T}\int_0^T f(x)dx\ge e^{{1\over T}\int_0^T \ln f(x)dx}$$in an arbitrary interval $(0,T)$.

so naturally, my question is: **is this relation even true for any positive $f(x)$? If so, what is a formal proof for that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation is true, it is [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form)
$$
\varphi \left({1\over T}\int_0^T f(x) \, dx \right)\le {1\over T}\int_0^T \varphi( f(x)) \, dx \, ,
$$

applied to the convex function $\varphi(t) = - \ln t$.

Comment: And the cited Wikipedia article contains a proof.

Comment: Thanks. Nice answer!